# Issues with SVG objects on Mobile

Tags: javascript, css, svg, mobile

I have tried everything but I think I'm just a bit over my head here.  I have created a site that on desktop works perfectly, but, on mobile, the hover elements just will not work.  I'm using SVG Objects.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>F1 2021: Round 22 Abu Dhabi Grand Prix</title>
</head>

<body>

<style>
.circuit-map {
position: relative;
background-image: url(/circuits/round-01/bahrain.svg);
background-position: center;
overflow: hidden;
background-size: cover;
}
.circuit-map > img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    
}

.circuit-map .circuit-controls {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    transition: 0.3s;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.circuit-map .circuit-controls img {
    display: none;
    width: calc(100%);
    min-width: calc(100%);
}

.circuit-map .circuit-controls#statsLeft,
.circuit-map .circuit-controls#statsRight {
    top: 0;
    width: 4%;
    height: 84%;
    margin: 4.4% 0;
}
.circuit-map .circuit-controls#statsLeft {
    left: 0;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
.circuit-map .circuit-controls#statsRight {
    right: 0;
}

.circuit-map .circuit-controls#statsLeft:hover,
.circuit-map .circuit-controls#statsRight:hover {
    width: 95.65%;
}

.circuit-map .circuit-controls#statsTop,
.circuit-map .circuit-controls#statsBottom {
    left: 0;
    height: 7.5%;
    width: 91.5%;
    margin: 0 4.25%;
}

.circuit-map .circuit-controls#statsTop {
    top: 0;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
.circuit-map .circuit-controls#statsBottom {
    bottom: 0;
    flex-direction:column;
}

.circuit-map .circuit-controls#statsTop:hover,
.circuit-map .circuit-controls#statsBottom:hover {
    height: 92.1%;
}

</style>

<header>
<hr style="height:1px;background-color:white">
<h1>Round 01 Bahrain Grand Prix</h1>
<h2 style="font-size: 36px;">Sakhir Circuit, Bahrain</h2>
<br>
<h2>31 Dec, 2021</h2>

</header>
<br>
<br>
<section class="container">
<div class="circuit-map">
<img
id="circuitImage"
src="circuit.svg"
alt="Sakhir Circuit, Bahrain"
/>
<div class="circuit-controls" id="statsLeft">
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="starting-grid.svg"></object></div>
<div class="circuit-controls" id="statsRight">
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="race-results.svg"></object></div>
<div class="circuit-controls" id="statsBottom">
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="sprint-results.svg"></object></div>
<div class="circuit-controls" id="statsTop">
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="stats-top.svg"></object></div>
</div>

<script>
const circuitImageDOM = document.getElementById('circuitImage');

function calculateStatsSizes() {
const statsXDOM = [
document.querySelector('#statsLeft object'),
document.querySelector('#statsRight object'),
];
const statsYDOM = [
document.querySelector('#statsTop object'),
document.querySelector('#statsBottom object'),
];

const parentSizes =
statsXDOM[0].parentElement.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect();
const parentWidth = parentSizes.width;
const parentHeight = parentSizes.height;

statsXDOM.forEach(stat => {
stat.style.minWidth = `${parentWidth}px`;
stat.style.display = 'block';
});
statsYDOM.forEach(stat => {
stat.style.minHeight = `${parentHeight}px`;
stat.style.display = 'block';
});
}
circuitImageDOM.addEventListener('load', calculateStatsSizes);
window.addEventListener('resize', calculateStatsSizes);

circuitImageDOM.setAttribute(
'src',
`${circuitImageDOM.getAttribute(
'src'
)}?preventCache=${Math.random()}`
);
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

I just cannot seem to get this working on mobile - as a reference, here is the published site https://drivetodescribe.com/circuits/round-01/index.html.  Can anyone help with this?

Comment: I'm afraid you're going to have to be more specific than your entire home page and a link to your website. What SVG doesn't work? Can you narrow it down to one element? You may use https://jsfiddle.net if you like.

Comment: Sorry I thought I was clear - on mobile, the 4 SVGs that sit over the circuit image are not responsive.  So on desktop, when you hover over them, they reveal themselves, but on mobile, nothing happens.  I'm not sure how to explain it any better - like I said at the top, it's a little bit over my head

The reason I didn't use jsfiddle.net is because the SVGs are files so jsfiddle doesn't really work - but here it is if you want it https://jsfiddle.net/2gn4yLav/.

Comment: You mean "track info", "starting grid" and "race results"? Not exactly sure why you're using SVGs there. A `div` would work just the same and you can more easily customize them with CSS. That being said, mobile devices don't detect your finger hovering over web elements, so you need to change your mechanics. Maybe a click with `touchend`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're talking about hovering on mobile devices. But unless you have a mouse or other pointing device connected to the mobile device (which is obviously not normal), you can't count on a hover on mobile as it's only recording touch.

Normally you would use a `click`-event, pointerevents like `pointerdown` or `pointerup` (which work for both mouse and touch). Or direct touch events (like `touchstart` or `touchend`, which only work on touch input).

So you could convert the concept from hovering over the sides to something like toggling the sides on or off. Or having them open on a `pointerdown` (or `touchstart`) and close on a `pointerup` (or `touchend`).

Comment: Ok great - thanks for the help - I’ll try this and let you know :)